# Inconsistent preview with unclosed <pre> tag

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, markdown-preview, pre

The following text:

```
* Boo
<pre>
Zoo
```

Is previewed as

[image: previewed message]

But rendered (at least on my Firefox) as

[image: final message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

invalid markup may produce strange results in the preview; this isn't really something we plan to fix.